# After completion of MapReduce job, RunJar is still active

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I was executing few mapreduce program on the hadoop cluster. The programs executed successfully and gave the required output.

using jps command I noticed that RunJar was still running as the process. I stopped my cluster but still the process id was up.

I know that Hadoop jar invokes base Runjar for execution of jar, but is it normal that even after job completion the process is up?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pbsO.png)

if yes, in that care muliple Runjar instances will keep running, how can i make sure that after job completion, run jar even stops(I don't wish to kill the process)

Comment: Please check whether you have a hive cli opened in the system. RunJar can be a hive client, hiveserver service, hive metastore service etc.

Answer (score 0):

The RunJar process is normally the result of someone or something running “hadoop jar "

you can kill the process with:

> > kill 13082